# Update individual value in an xarray DataArray in-place?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Perhaps it's poor form, but is there a way to update a single value of an `xarray` DataArray in-place? I am performing a trend analysis in which I subset each (lat, lon) cell and analyze over the time slice.

I want to be able to do something like:

```
output_array.loc[dict(lat=i, lon=j)]['intercept'] = intercept
```

or

```
output_array.sel(lat=i, lon=j)['intercept'] = intercept
```

In which `intercept` is a single value (float) to be updated in the `output['intercept']` DataArray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xarray.DataArray`s are basically wrappers around `numpy` ndarrays, which means you can just modify the underlying `numpy` array.

You can access (and modify) the array with either the `.data` or `.values` property.

```py
import xarray as xr

# load testdata
x = xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")

# keep second reference of array just for showcasing
arr = x.air.data

# it's the same
assert arr is x.air.data

# indices
i,j,k = (0,0,0)

print(x.air.data[i,j,k], arr[i,j,k])
# 241.2 241.2

# new value
x.air.data[i,j,k] = 0

# check
print(x.air.data[i,j,k], arr[i,j,k])
# 0.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 3):

To add onto @val's excellent answer, it's possible to mutate the array directly, without needing to go through the `.data` attribute:

```
In [5]: x.air[i,j,k] = 0

In [6]: print(x.air.data[i,j,k], arr[i,j,k])
0.0 0.0
```